# SQL Server - calculating continuous membership

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Here's the logic for calculation I am trying to do: I have to calculate members who are continuously been enrolled in membership. For example John membership ended on 1-1-2017 but he joined again before 2-15-2017 then he is counted as a eligible member, but if he joins later than 45 days he is not eligible for membership count. I tried using ranking function as well as tried using `DATEDIFF` function, seems like doesn't works.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

```
| ID | NAME  | TERMINATIONDATE | STARTDATE |
|------------------------------------------|
| 2  | John  | 1-1-2017        | 2-16-2017 |
| 3  | Harry | 12-1-2016       | 1-1-2016  |
| 4  | Rob   | active          | 1-1-2015  |
```

So I need the count of ID's which are not terminated, and if they are terminated and started with 45 days of termination , count it too as eligible members.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful and eliminate assumptions

Comment: sorry about that:

Comment: added the sample data, but came in one line.

Comment: Your sample doesn't quite match what your explain in your question.You said John joined on 02/15/2017 but your sample has a start date of 02/16/2017. Typo?

Comment: Hi Chris, so here's the situation; John got terminated on 1-1-2017 and started again on 2-16-2017 i.e days passed is not greater than 45 days. so i want to count John as a continuous member whereas anyone with more than 45 days gap in the membership is not counted. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the dateadd function to compare the start date to the termination date:

```
select
count(*)
from members
where isnull(termination_date,'') = ''
or dateadd(d,45,termination_date) > start_date
```

One thing I noticed in your example data is that the value of 'active' is in the termination date column. If that is how your data is, I would recommend against doing that and instead using a value NULL for all members that do not have a termination date.

**Edited:**
If your termination date is actually "stringly-typed", you can use the following query to scrub out the "active" value:

```
select
count(*)
from members
where termination_date = 'active'
or dateadd(d,45, replace(termination_date,'active','')) > start_date
```